# search in array with startswith and ignore first 3 characters in this array

Tags: c#

i have string[] _comboBoxItems which has 271 elements like

```
a1 03154643
a1 03450324
a2 08432155
a1 13549812
```

now i want to search in this array. If i write 03 i want to get

```
a1 03154643
a1 03450324
```

how can i ignore a1 (first tree letters). I want to use comboBoxItems .startswith() but i don't know how to remove a1 when searching

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first select the substring that starts from the fourth character of each item:

```
var text = "03";
var matches = comboBox.Items.OfType<string>()
                            .Where(s => s.SubString(3).StartsWith(text));
```

The query uses `OfType` to make sure that you are only going to process strings and to cast them appropriately.

**Update:** If there are going to be strings with length < 3 characters inside the combo box (which from your description does sound unlikely), then you should also check for that eventuality:

```
var matches = comboBox.Items.OfType<string>()
                          .Where(s => s.Length > 3 && s.SubString(3).StartsWith(text));
```

Comment: Will fail on strings with less than 3 characters.

Comment: @leppie as stated by the OP all strings are 11 chars long, therefore it's okay

Comment: @Matten: Purely a side-comment, just in case :)

Comment: thx for fast answer. Is it possible to be more generic. Instead of removing first 3 remove everything to first " "? I see that can be a12 not just a1, a2,...

Comment: @leppie: Updated answer, but from the OP's description that doesn't sound likely.

Comment: @senzacionale yes, just replace `s.SubString(3)` with `s.SubString(s.IndexOf(" ") + 1)`

Comment: @senzacionale to match upto first " " use this lambda: (s => Regex.IsMatch(s, ".*? " + text)). This uses a non-greedy Regex to match any number of characters upto first " ".

Comment: You can probably replace OfType with Cast as the items ARE strings

Comment: @vc74: Probably, but not definitely (they might be some other type that overrides `ToString`).

Comment: @Jon: OP says that he has `string[] _comboBoxItems`, therefore I think you don't need to use `OfType<>()`

Comment: @Huusom can you write whole code. regex is nice solution. Jon thx

Answer (score 1):

Full code with RegEx

```
public static string[] Filter(this string[] source, string pattern) {
  var rx = new Regex(".*? " + pattern);
  return source.Where(s => rx.IsMatch(s)).ToArray();
}
```

Test with:

```
var values = new string[] { "a1 03154643", "a1 03450324", "a2 08432155", "a1 13549812" };
var res = values.Filter("03");
```

Note, it still needs error handling and parameter validation to be production ready.